# keep doing scanf for all input in command line. C program

Tags: c, command-line, input, scanf

I am trying to get all the input from the command line and putting it in a linked list.
the numbers from the command line are of this format 0-1 2-3 4-9 etcc
Here is what I did to store a pair of numbers in two variables:

```
scanf("%d-%d", &a, &b);
```

Now, this scanf statement is inside a loop and my question is: what is the condition of the loop?
I want to keep doing scanf until all the input is finished.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define "until all the input is finished"? If you answer this, you'll get your loop condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A famous, if not notorious characteristic of `scanf` is that it will leave data in input buffer when reading non-string data(e.g, `int`). Check out here: [Leave data in input buffer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cpwiki/index.php?title=Scanf_woes).

Try this:

```
do
{
  int x = scanf("%d-%d", &a, &b);
}while ((x != EOF) && (getchar() != '\n'));
```

You need to compare `scanf` output with EOF. And most importantly, you need flush out the `'\n'` left by `scanf` in input buffer.

Comment: And how is this EOF reached? If I input a pair of numbers per row and keep hitting newlines when I want to stop nothing happens.

Comment: @Tudor, please with this again.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is what I was trying to do.
And the getchar is the most important part like you said, without it the user needs to enter EOF manually)
Thanks again!